# File read/write methods

Tags: php, file-system, io, sync

I'm using some simple files for caching and some basic user data. I was first just using `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()`, but realized this could quickly go wrong when traffic starts increasing.

I've been trying to figure out how to do it properly with `flock()`, correct file modes, etc, and come up with the following functions. Have I understood things correctly? Will this be safe in most normal use-cases, with small-to-medium web site usage?

```
class File
{

    public static function read($path, $default = NULL)
    {
        $fp = @fopen($path, 'r');
        if( ! $fp)
            return $default;

        flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
        $data = fread($fp, filesize($path));
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        return $data;
    }


    public static function write($path, $data)
    {
        self::check(dirname($path));

        $fp = fopen($path, 'c');
        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        ftruncate($fp, 0);
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fflush($fp);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        return $data;
    }



    public static function check($dir)
    {
        if( ! is_dir($dir))
        {
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#System_call
            @mkdir($dir, 06750, true);
            @chmod($dir, 06750);
        }
        return $dir;
    }
}
```

Some particular things:

- Should using `LOCK_SH` in `read` allow for multiple simultaneous reads?
  (which will be the bulk of what's happening since writes will happen quite seldom)
- Will using `LOCK_EX` in `write` make sure nobody else is reading or writing while the file is changed?
- Will using the directory permission mask `06750` makes sure that

  1. any files created in that directory will get the same permissions as the directory, and
  2. the directory/file will only be writable by the web server user and readable by its group?

Comment: I've already encountered with this situation where records of two more users gets merged. So, not sure this will help you out.

Comment: @Haridarshan what do you mean? users gets merged?

Comment: If two users visit the site/portal at same timestamp and the visitor log of one user is getting written at the same visitor log of second user also gets written in the same. Because of which these two records of both users get merged. We're not using any kind of locking because that will delay the service we are provided. So, to handle such kind of problem we are using stomp to write the visitor logs. On an average we gets around 1M visitors.

Comment: So performance aside, the locking would've fixed the merging problem?

Comment: We've tried the locking also but that delays the portal loading and we lose traffic. So, we're using stomp to write the log data in messaging queue i.e `activemq` and one fuse api to write the data into table/file.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be useful to look at [the manual page for the linux function with the same name](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock):

> **flock**() places advisory locks only; given suitable permissions on a file, a process is free to ignore the use of **flock**() and perform I/O on the file.<sup>[1](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)</sup>

You asked:

> *Should using `LOCK_SH` in `read()` allow for multiple simultaneous reads?*

From the [linux manual page for `flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock):

> #### LOCK_SH
>
> Place a shared lock. More than one process may hold a shared lock for a given file at a given time.

---

Should the `check()` method handle the case where the directory does exist but is not writable (i.e. using [`is_writable()`](https://php.net/is_writable))? And what if the user is not able to update permissions?

The [`flock()` function](https://php.net/flock) returns **true** on success or **false** on failure [<sup>2</sup>](https://php.net/flock#refsect1-function.flock-returnvalues) so perhaps it would be useful to use those values to determine if subsequent operations should be attempted.

While using [`file_put_contents()` function](https://php.net/file_put_contents) were you using **LOCK_EX** in the [`$flags` (i.e. 3<sup>rd</sup> ) parameter)](https://php.net/file_put_contents#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-parameters)? If not, that might be a technique to simplify the `write` function.

I can’t think of a reason the `write` function would need to return the data to be written- is that imperative for your code?

Answer (score 1):

**Suppressing errors**

Error suppression should be avoided if possible as it doesn't just suppress the error that you are trying to stop, but will also suppress errors that you didn't predict would ever occur. This will make debugging a nightmare.

Other then that, looks nice.

Comment: Good points. Although in my case, for  `read`, if it fails, I just want to return the `$default`, and don't really care why it failed. This is why I chose to just suppress any errors and check if `$fp` is falsy right afterwards.

As for in the `write` function, I'm not sure why it would ever fail, and if it did, not sure I could do anything sensible about it anyways.

Comment: You start by saying you should not just suppress the errors. You go on by saying you should suppress the errors. I think you meant something else there.

Comment: No, i'm saying surpress the errors & handle them when they occur. The error handler gets still called when surpressing errors with @ (With an error level of 0)

Comment: But i get the confusion, changed my answer.